# Avalonia Datagrid cell value does not update when model property is updated from another column

Tags: .net-core, datagrid, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have a Datagrid with two columns that bind to the same property

```cs
<DataGrid
    Margin="10"
    BorderBrush="Black"
    BorderThickness="1"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
    Items="{Binding Logs}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn
            Header="Temp Date"
            Binding="{Binding Date,Mode=TwoWay}"
            >
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn
            Header="Calendar Column"
            CellTemplate="{Binding TestTemplate}"
            CellEditingTemplate="{Binding EditingTemplate}"
            >
            
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    
</DataGrid>
```

I have also created a cell template in the view model as such:

```cs
// Cell Data Template
 TestTemplate = new FuncDataTemplate<EntryLog>((value, namescope) =>

   new TextBlock
   {
       [!TextBlock.TextProperty] = new Binding("Date",BindingMode.TwoWay),
   });
```

```cs
// Cell Editing Data Template
EditingTemplate = new FuncDataTemplate<EntryLog>((value, namescope) =>
{
    var grid = new Grid();
    var tb = new TextBlock
    {
        [!TextBlock.TextProperty] = new Binding("Date", BindingMode.TwoWay),
    };
    grid.Children.Add(tb);

    var calendar = new Calendar();
    calendar.DisplayDate = value.Date;
    calendar.SelectedDate = value.Date;

    Popup popup = new Popup();
    popup.Child = calendar;
    popup.IsOpen = true;


    calendar.SelectedDatesChanged += (s, e) => 
    {
        value.Date = calendar.SelectedDate.Value.Date;
        //tb.Text = value.Date.ToString();

    };
    grid.Children.Add(popup);
    
    return grid;
});
```

In the UI, it looks like this when editing:

[image: Datagrid]

**My issue is, whenever I update one column, the other column does not get updated**. The itemsource is a Observable Collection of my model

My model:

```cs
public class EntryLog : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime _date;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get => _date;
        set
        {
            if (_date != value)
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Date)));

            _date = value;
        }
    }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Hours { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

Was wondering if anyone can help me out? Maybe I'm missing something that I just can't identify.

Comment: Make `EntryLog` inherit `ReactiveObject` and use `this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged()` and try that. Code looks like it should work to be honest.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, have you confirmed that the calendar selected value is actually setting the property on the underlying `LogEntry` instance?

Comment: @Jammer yes, I literally just figured it out. This is what I get for trying to code even though i'm exhausted. Thanks for responding! appreciate it.

Comment: Yup, I missed that too ...

Comment: Still, go reactive if you can ...

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I was invoking the propertychanged event before the change of the actual value. The correct way is just to swap that:

```
public class EntryLog : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime _date;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get => _date;
        set
        {
            if (_date != value)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Date)));
              _date = value;
            }           
        }
    }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Hours { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```